# Access denied error unloading hive

Tags: batch-file, hive, registry

Windows 7 batch file - I want all current users to execute a "runonce"

- `%1` is a username from a for loop
- `%2` is a value name
- `%3` is the data for the value

```
REG LOAD HKU\TEMP "%1\NTUSER.DAT"
REG ADD HKU\TEMP\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v %2 /t REG_SZ /d %3 /f
REG UNLOAD HKU\TEMP
```

*Access denied* error when `reg unload` executes.
I run as admin, logged in as local admin.
No other errors.

Can you provide a simple resolution?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my Windows 10 machine. Do you have some registry related settings that you did not tell us?

Comment: You cannot change the hive for an 'in use' profile, could that be the reason. For an end user to update their own registry profile like this you'd need to add the information directly to their currently open hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility that the `Reg UnLoad` may try to run before the new data has completed being added. I have added a `Timeout` command in the example code below to give it a little longer.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RKL=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
Set "RKV=%~1"
Set "RKD=%~2"
Set "RKP=Temp"

For /F "UseBackQTokens=1*Delims==" %%A In (`WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "Loaded!='True' And Special!='True'" Get LocalPath /Value 2^>Nul`
) Do For %%C In ("%%B") Do (
    Reg Load "HKU\%RKP%" "%%~C\NTUSER.DAT"
    Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
    Reg Add "HKU\%RKP%\%RKL%" /V "%RKV%" /D "%RKD%" /F>NUL
    Timeout 2 /NoBreak>Nul
    Reg UnLoad "HKU\%RKP%"
)
```

To use the code above, replace the `%~1` and `%~2` with the non double quoted strings you were previously sending as `%2` and `%3` and try again.

Comment: **1**. The `Loaded` property tells nothing about load the `LocalPath` hive file into the registry. Check `SID` property. **2**. You must use `REG SAVE` before `Reg UnLoad` for the change to take effect at a user next login. **3**. Pay particular attention to the current user and _fake_ `C:\Users\DefaultAppPool`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @JosefZ; the `Loaded` property simply prevents a profile which is 'in use' at the time of query from being loaded. I don't need to save a new hive and from my experience of many years ago I don't recall ever having used `reg save` with `reg load` and `reg unload`. I understood the OP was logged in as Administrator, which is by my determination a `Loaded` and `Special` account and therefore excluded. I haven't wrote the loop as a replacement for the OP's, _(they're using a list in a for loop)_, just as a test to try to isolate the error reported.

Comment: I discovered that the code works fine if I reboot before running it, not just logging off and back on as local admin. I guess Windows doesn't free up all of a user's handles if you just log the user off.  I will also review "Reg Save" to see if that might eliminate future issues I might run into. Thanks all for the speedy replies!  I consider this request closed.

Comment: @ErikTangen If this answer was helpful, please **consider marking it as accepted**. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.